# Assistance with SQL Query to break down bill of materials

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to breakdown a BOM into its lowest items. I have got 2 tables.

Table A:

```
ITEM        FORMULA
--------------------
7024        BDD39           
7024        BDD94
```

Table B

```
FORMULA         RAW_ITEMS
---------------------------------------
BDD94           BioxDD 94 RMW0005                                
BDD94           BioxDD 94 RMP0007                  
BDD94           BioxDD 94 RMD0010                                   
BDD94           BioxDD 94 RMH0009                    
BDD39           BioxDD 39 RMA0005                              
BDD39           BioxDD 39 RMW0006                               
BDD39           BioxDD 39 RMS0005
```

Is there any hint as to how to go about to replace the item in Table A with all the 3 items in Table B?

My expected output is:

```
Item 
-----------------------------------------
7024 BDD39              BioxDD 39 RMA0005                              
7024 BDD39              BioxDD 39 RMW0006                               
7024 BDD39              BioxDD 39 RMS0005  
7024 BDD94              BioxDD 94 RMH0007
7024 BDD94              BioxDD 94 RMA0007                              
7024 BDD94              BioxDD 94 RMW0010                               
7024 BDD94              BioxDD 94 RMS0009
```

Answer (score 2):

By using CONCAT function and INNER JOIN, you may get the desired output :

```
SELECT CONCAT(a.Item, ' ', a.Formula) AS Item,
       b.raw_items
 FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b
   ON ( b.Formula = a.Formula )
WHERE a.Formula = 'BDD39';
```

or Use without assigning the vale *BDD39* to *Formula*:

```
SELECT Item, raw_items
  FROM
(  
SELECT CONCAT(a.Item, ' ', a.Formula) AS Item,
       b.raw_items,
       dense_rank() over (order by a.Formula) dr
 FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b
   ON ( b.Formula = a.Formula )
) q
WHERE q.dr = 1;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7fb28/7)

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is simply an inner join, which is the basis of SQL:

```
SELECT 
A.ITEM,
A.FORMULA,
B.RAW_ITEMS
FROM 
TableA A
INNER JOIN
TableB B
ON A.Formula = B.Formula
```

If it all has to be in one column you just concatenate it up. Here's one way

```
SELECT 
A.ITEM + ' ' +
A.FORMULA + ' ' + 
B.RAW_ITEMS As Item
FROM 
TableA A
INNER JOIN
TableB B
ON A.Formula = B.Formula
```

Here's another

```
SELECT CONCAT(
A.ITEM, ' ',
A.FORMULA,' ',
B.RAW_ITEMS) As Item
FROM 
TableA A
INNER JOIN
TableB B
ON A.Formula = B.Formula
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(ITEM, " ", TA.FORMULA, " ",  RAW_ITEMS) AS ITEM
FROM TABLEA TA, TABLEB TB
WHERE TA.FORMULA = TB.FORMULA
```